# SVN - Propagate changes to subsequent branches

Tags: svn

I'm using SVN. The repository structure is like this:

```
 Project
  |
  |-->tags
  |-->trunk
  |-->branches
      |
      |-->01.01.00
      |    |-->prj_folder
      |
      |-->01.10.00
      |    |-->prj_folder
      |
      |-->02.00.00
           |-->prj_folder
```

(version numbers are just an example)

By default changes committed on branch 01.01.00 **DO NOT** affect code already committed on other branches.

What should I do if want to obtain the opposite behavior?

In other words, what should I do if want to commit changes on branch 01.01.00 and then propagate those changes (and only those) to another branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a "cherry pick" merge...

You select just the commits in one branch you're interested in an merge them into a another branch (or trunk)